# Recording current date&time in SharePoint Online list keeps breaking - need a stable solution

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I am currently working on building a SharePoint Online list tool for customers that, among other things, records time stamps that will help the customer track when certains steps were completed. The idea is simple: I have built a button that, when pressed, records the **current time and date**. I am using JSON column formatting.

Simplified, the button code looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "cursor": "pointer"
  },
  "txtContent": "Click me",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "Change": "@now"
          }
  }
}
```

There are two options for the column *Change*: it can be a date&time column or a text column. I originally put it as date&time, but very quickly stumbled upon a problem: if my browser is in English, it tries to record the date in the US format, which my list (German locale) doesn't accept. So I made it a **text field** that needs to just record the time stamp for a human to see.

When I started building it, I used "=@now" instead of "@now" and it worked for a couple of weeks, then suddenly stopped working. I took away the "=" and it started working again. Click the button - record current time and date.

There was still a problem of format, though. If people worked from different browsers, there would be a wild mixture of date formats and it could become confusing to the user, so I formatted *Change* column to always show **European format**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString(@currentField) + ' ' + toLocaleTimeString(@currentField)"
}
```

And this worked just fine until it suddenly stopped working a couple of days ago, showing **"Invalid Date Invalid Date"** instead. It stops showing the error if I take away locale formatting, but then the previous problem is back. Not to mention, it is unwise to release this tool when it keeps breaking every couple of weeks.

**What I also tried:**

1. Created a calculated column with the formula =NOW() and tried to record the current time based on its value, not relying on JSON. Didn't work: the column only updates itself **after** updating the list item, so after pressing the button it records not the current time, **but the previous time** saved there.
2. Pulling the date from "Modified" - the same problem,  it is not the current date and time.
3. Creating a column displaying "txtContent" : "@now" and trying to pull information from it - nope, since JSON, in this case, is only showing the user something and not recording anything, thus the column value is actually empty.

I would appreciate any sort of assistance in the matter. I am not an expert in CSS, but I've been building JSON formatted lists for some time and they worked - though not relying so heavily on times and dates. With this date situation, even the official list formatting samples on GitHub break sometimes (this breaks for me: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/date-update-format)

Maybe you guys see something I  don't? Or maybe there is a neat and stable workaround to record the current time? Have a good day!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?  It must be a long standing bug because `@now` was working completely fine for us when setting a date column with `customRowAction` a few weeks ago and now it has just stopped.  It just displays the same error as you, i.e:  "Enter a date and time like this: 23/12/2012 2:25PM"