# Setting Microsoft List date column value to @now causes error: 'Enter a date and time like this'

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

Using JSON column formatting, I have set up a button in a Microsoft List that, when clicked, sets the value of three columns:

```
"customRowAction": {
"action": "setValue",
"actionInput": {
"St01Status": "=if([$St01Status] == 'Completed', 'Pending', 'Completed')",
"St01Appver": "=if([$St01Status] == 'Completed', '', '@me')",
"St01AppDate": "=if([$St01Status] == 'Completed', '', '@now')"
}
```

I have found that this line causes an error when using Chrome browser on one computer:

```
"St01AppDate": "=if([$St01Status] == 'Completed', '', '@now')"
```

The error is:

> "Enter a date and time like this: 23/12/2012 2:25PM"

[image]

The column type is date that includes time.

So it doesn't like what `@now` is generating.

However on other computers, it does not cause an error, and performs the desired behaviour.

It seems that this is caused by the `Language` setting in Chrome browser.

The button works as desired when language is set to `English (United States)`.

The button causes an error when language is set to `English (Australia)`.

Strangely, the locale of the SITE where the list resides is `English (Australia)` - so you would think the behaviour would be the other way around.

**Question**

How can I create a `@now` value that will work regardless of the language setting of the browser?

Below are screenshots of the language settings in both browsers and the site locale settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

For reference, related questions were asked here but never received an answer:

[Recording current date&time in SharePoint Online list keeps breaking - need a stable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76312983)

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/add-date-created-entered-to-json-code-for-sharepoint-list/m-p/3618991

Comment: Try this: `"St01AppDate": "=if([$St01Status] == 'Completed', '', toLocaleDateString(@now))"`. let me know if it works for you. Are you using date only column or you included time as well in column settings?

Comment: I am away from computer now,  but will test asap.  The column type is date that includes time, but I have tried changing it to date only and it showed the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I have a date & time (with date only settings) column in our SharePoint list.

I am using this JSON and it works fine for me:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Update item",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "DateColumn": "=if([$Status]=='Completed',[$DateColumn],toLocaleDateString(@now))"
    }
  }
}
```

Where `DateColumn` and `Status` are internal names of SharePoint list columns. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

---

**Update from comments**:

I have tested by including time in the date column settings as well and it works fine for me (set 12:00AM as default time as I haven't passed any time in the JSON):

[image]

**Language settings**:

[image]

Comment: I tried this in both browsers:  `"St01AppDate": "=if([$St01Status] == 'Completed', '', toLocaleDateString(@now))"`, and it gave me the same error in both browsers:  `Enter a date and time like this: 23/12/2012 2:25PM`.

Comment: Can you try copying & using this: `"St01AppDate": "=if([$St01Status]=='Completed',[$St01AppDate],toLocaleDateString(@now))"`. It worked for me in both English and English-Australia languages. I have tested by switching language settings in chrome browser.

Comment: I copied and pasted that and got same error in both browsers.

Comment: FYI - as mentioned in other comment, my date column is date with time included.

Comment: Strange, it works for me fine as you can see in the screenshot I attached. Are you using [Targeted or Standard release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide) tenant? Not sure it makes any difference in the targeted release tenant as it received all the latest updates.

Comment: I have tested by including time in the date column settings as well, check updated answer. If it still not working for you, try raising support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Answer (score 0):

Try with ISO Format:

```
"getYear(@now)+'-'+(getMonth(@now)+1)+'-'+getDate(@now)+' '+toLocaleTimeString(@now)"
```